# AWS Elastic Beanstalk load balancer is redirecting to HTTPS - does my app still need UseHttpsRedirection() and UseHsts()?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

First, let me say that this is the first time I have written an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app and first time learning AWS with Elastic Beanstalk.  So if it seems like I'm confused... it's because I am.  ;-)

I have two AWS environments - one is Staging and one is Production.  The Staging environment has no SSL certificate and no load balancer.  It only listens on port 80.

Production has a load balancer set up with my SSL certificate, and is set up to redirect all port 80 traffic to port 443.

Port 80 = Redirect to https://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}
Status code:HTTP_301

Port 443 = Forward to my-target-group: 1 (100%)
Group-level stickiness: Off

When I generated the new web app in VS 2019, I opted in on HTTPS/HSTS by checking "Configure for HTTPS".  So it has this in Startup.cs:

```
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

I am getting this error in my Windows event log in Staging and Production: *“Failed to determine the https port for redirect”*

I tried the suggestion from [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl)

```
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
    });
```

But that messed up the Staging environment because there's nothing listening on port 443.

Since Staging is only using HTTP, and Production is redirecting to HTTPS at the load balancer, should I just remove the UseHsts() and UseHttpsRedirection() altogether from my Startup?  Will that pose any security problems - I do want traffic encrypted over the internet but I don't think it's necessary between the load balancer and the EC2 instance, correct?

Or do I need Forwarded headers, as suggested at [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer)?

Answer (score 1):

> I do want traffic encrypted over the internet but I don't think it's necessary between the load balancer and the EC2 instance, correct?

Correct. That's how it is usually setup. So you usually would have SSL termination on your load balancer (LB), and then from LB to your instance it would be regular http traffic:

```
Client----(https)---->LB----(http)---->instances
```

> does my app still need UseHttpsRedirection() and UseHsts()?

No, as your app is just recieving http traffic only from the LB.

Comment: Thank you, Marcin.  Do I need Forwarded headers, or is that also only needed if the web app is receiving HTTPS traffic directly?  I ask because the Microsoft page I linked to in my question is not clear on when this should be used, or I'm likely not understanding their terminology.

Comment: Further research on this topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906676/enabling-hsts-in-aws-elb-application-load-balacer) says UseHsts() should be enabled in my app because it will still go back to the browser in HTTPS from the Elastic LB.  Correct?