# How to implement HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) on AWS Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-alb

how to enable HSTS in ALB, spent several hours searching for information, but in vain. I did not find what interested me. Does such a possibility exist at all?

Comment: Please see the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906676/enabling-hsts-in-aws-elb-application-load-balacer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling HSTS in AWS ELB application load balacer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906676/enabling-hsts-in-aws-elb-application-load-balacer)